# Entries(<key,values>) are not entered in a map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, comparison

I want save values in a `std::map` if an hash function return a value that isn't already contained in the map. The data structure is:

```
std::map<uint8_t* , MyObject* , lex_compare> mymap;
```

where `uint8_t*` point to a C-style array of 128 bit (`uint8_t hash_value[16]`) that contain the hash function applied to a field of class `MyObject`. I use `lex_compare` for a personalized comparison:

```
struct lex_compare {
bool operator() (const uint8_t *hash1, const uint8_t *hash2) const {
    /*for(int i=0 ; i<16 ; i++)
             {
                 cout<<(unsigned int)hash1[i]<<" ";
             }
             cout<<endl<<endl;
             for(int i=0 ; i<16 ; i++)
             {
                 cout<<(unsigned int)hash2[i]<<" ";
             }
    int m=memcmp(hash2,hash1,16);
    cout<<"m is è"<<m<<endl;*/
    return (memcmp(hash2,hash1,16)<0); //compare 16 byte.
    }
};
```

To ensure insertion only if an hash value is not already contained in the map I use:

```
while(mymap.size()<R)
{
myObject *temp_o  = new myObject(parameters);
uint8_t hash_result = my_hash_function(myObject->return_field()) // return_field is a specific field of myObject 
mymap.insert(make_pair(hash_result,temp_o));
}
```

But only one element is inserted in `mymap`, thus I go in endless loop. Why? I can not explain it.  Look at `lex_compare` I saw that this function return always zero value (because is called on 2 equals elements). May be is a trivial problem, but I'm not able to see it.

EDIT:
I correct  problem in comparison function. But later correction main problem remains

Comment: Your comparison returns `true` for both greater-than and less-than.

Comment: Your hash_result is a uint_8. You don't show actual code. I suspect that your hashing function returns a pointer to a local array.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: try with

```
return (memcmp(hash2,hash1,16) > 0);
```

Long answer: `memcpy()` return a negative value if the first argument is lower than the second, zero if they are equal and a positive value if the first value is greater than the second.

But your `operator()` return a boolean. So negative and positive value are converted in `true` and zero is converted in `false`.
So, according your `operator()`, `hash1` is lower that `hash2` if they are different.
And the bad part is that, if `hash1` and `hash2` are different, `hash1` result lower than `hash2` **and** `hash2` result lower than `hash1`. This give to the program an undefined behavior.

Solution: modify the return instruction or in this way

```
return (memcmp(hash2,hash1,16) > 0);
```

or as follows

```
return (memcmp(hash2,hash1,16) < 0);
```

to be sure that `true == operator()(hash1, hash2)` imply that `false == operator()(hash2, hash1)`

Comment: Trivial mistake. Surely you are right. I'm trying (it's a great library where compilation time is high)

Comment: @Umbert - I'm reasonably sure that is a problem; I don't know if it's the only problem.

Comment: The problem remain, namely an element alone is entered in the map. The operator() return always 0, because is called on the same hash elements but a print in the loop gives me a different element. Thus, I still do not understand where the mistake is.  Surely, that you detect was one. Why operator() is called on 2 equals hash values?

Comment: The operator () returns true or false. The operator is called twice to test on equality. If it returns false in both tests the values are equal.

Comment: As i stated already as a comment under your question: _I suspect that your hashing function returns a pointer to a local array_. So while you calculate the new hash you change the one in the map.

Comment: I even understood it a moment before you made the comment (your previous one I did not see it). I write the new hash value always in the same array: then the previous pointer inserted in the map points to the same current. I have to go on holiday :) Thanks